# PHP post octet stream with CURL

Tags: c#, php, curl, windows-phone-8

I try to follow this sample in PHP
https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh868252.aspx

What will be the equivalent of this peace of code in PHP?

```
byte[] contentInBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xml);
...
using (Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
            requestStream.Write(contentInBytes, 0, contentInBytes.Length);
```

If i try this, this is not working

```
$sendPush = curl_init();
curl_setopt($sendPush, CURLOPT_URL, $uri);  
curl_setopt($sendPush, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
$headers = array('Content-Type: text/xml',"Content-Type: text/xml","X-WNS-RequestForStatus:true", "X-WNS-Type:wns/toast","Content-Length: " . strlen($toastMessage) ,"X-WindowsPhone-Target: toast","Authorization: Bearer $accessToken");
curl_setopt($sendPush, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($sendPush, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($sendPush,CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($sendPush, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $toastMessage);
$output = curl_exec($sendPush);
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: do you get any error?

Comment: No, but the device (windows phone) can't read the notification.

Comment: can you please add the xml inside `$toastMessage`to your question?

Comment: Ok, i just fix it. PHP string are already array bytes. My $toastMessage was not correct. FYI the correct $toastMessage follow this template https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh761494.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: Nice to hear, by the way it would be good to post your solution as an answer

Answer (score 0):

The problem wasn't from CURL but from the $toastMessage string.
If you want to send WPS notifications, you need to use one of the format describe here
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh761494.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396